# ORDER on an INSERT TO

Tags: c#, oledb

I am using OLEDB to INSERT INTO an existing Excel worksheet. But I want to INSERT in a certain order. So I have this:

```
    File.Copy(lTemplateFolder + lFilename, lDistributorFolder + lFilename, true);
    string lConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + lDistributorFolder + "\\" + lFilename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"";
    DbProviderFactory lFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
    int lSequence = 0;

    using (DbConnection lConnection = lFactory.CreateConnection())
    {
        lConnection.ConnectionString = lConnectionString;
        lConnection.Open();

        foreach (DataRowView rowView in dv)
        {
            DataRow row = rowView.Row;

            lSequence++;

            using (DbCommand lCommand = lConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                lCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$]";
                lCommand.CommandText += "([First Name],[Last Name],[Title],[Company],[Address],[Address 2],[City],[State],[Zip],[Country],[Work phone],[Email],[Website],[Stamp Time],[Campaign],[Source],[Business Unit],[Market Segment],[Notes]) ";
                lCommand.CommandText += "VALUES(";
                lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["name"].ToString().Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
                lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["lastname"].ToString().Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
                lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["title"].ToString().Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
                lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["company"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
                lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["address"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
                lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["address2"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
                lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["city"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
                lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["state"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
                lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["zip"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
                lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["country"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
                lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["workphone"].ToString() + "\",";
                lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["email"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
                lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["website"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
                lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["stamptime"].ToString() + "\",";
                lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["campaign"].ToString().Replace("\"","\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
                lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["source"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";
                lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + row["notes"].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("&nbsp;", " ") + "\",";                    
                lCommand.CommandText += "\"" + "High" + "\"";

            lCommand.CommandText += ")";
            lCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        lConnection.Close();
    }
```

So what I want to do is take the `row["notes"].ToString()` and order the insert by `row["notes"].ToString().Count()` so it inserts the longest notes string first and so on. Is this possible? If it is how would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: There are fewer than never times when you need to do an ordered `INSERT`. If order is important, apply it during `SELECT` instead. Or in your case using a sort operation in the workbook.

Comment: I'm not doing any SELECT just an INSERT.

Comment: I understand that. What I'm saying is to just sort the data using Excel. If it were actually going into a database you could sort during `SELECT`. In general - whatever is *consuming* the data and presenting it to the user should be doing the ordering. **Ordering** data in a set is a presentational concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Insert in the order you want by simply load all the DataView (which come from Excel) into a list and then sort this list with the value of row["notes"].

```
   DataView d = null;//Load from Excel
   var rows = (from DataRowView rowView in d select rowView.Row).ToList();
   foreach (DataRow dataRow in rows.OrderByDescending(r=>(int)r["notes"]))
   {
      //Insert code here that you already have
   }
```